# Making SQL find the nearest result if it can't find the exact search term?

Tags: php, sql, forms

I am creating a multi-form search box that searches a Meat packaging database. The search works only if users are specific, I want them to be able to search the database without having to choose a specific option. Three of the form boxes are for users to search width, height and depth all numerical values, but they only return results if the user is exact with the sizes. I want the search to be able to return the nearest value if it cannot find an exact match to the one entered by the user.

Such as:

If user enters "252" in the width box, it will currently return "No searches found"
But there is a "251" in the database. So if the user types in "252" the SQL query then automatically looks for the nearest sizes and then displays in theory "251".

Here is the HTML and PHP:

```
<body>

    <form action="form3.php" method="post"> 
      <label for ="description">Description:</label>
      <input type="text" name="descrip" /><br />

      <label for ="trayheight">Trayheight:</label>
      <input type="text" name="height" /> <br /> 

      <label for ="traywidth">Traywidth:</label>
      <input type="text" name="width" /> <br />

      <label for ="traydepth">Traydepth:</label>
      <input type="text" name="depth" /> <br />

      <label for="trayrange">Trayrange: </label>
                <select name="trayrange">
                    <option value=""></option>

                    <option value="BBQ">BBQ</option>

                    <option value="Dessert">Dessert</option>

                    <option value="Display">Display</option>

                    <option value="Meat">Meat</option>   

                    <option value="Microwave">Microwave</option>

                    <option value="Party">Party</option>

                    <option value="Salad/Wet Pasta">Salad/Wet Pasta</option>

                    <option value="Snacks">Snacks</option>

                    <option value="Standard">Standard</option>

                </select>

        <label for ="traytype">Traytype: </label> 
            <select name="traytype">
                    <option value=""></option>

                <option value="Open">Open</option>

            <option value="Cavitised">Cavitised</option>

                    <option value="Lid">Lid</option>

                    <option value="Tray">Tray</option>

                    <option value="Coallition">Coallition</option>

                    <option value="Bowl">Bowl</option>

                    <option value="Hinge pack">Open</option>

                    <option value="Pot">Pot</option>

                    <option value="Base & Lid">Base and Lid</option>

                    <option value="Rectangular">Rectangular</option>

                    <option value="Specalist">Specialist</option>
            </select><br />

        <label for="trayshape">Trayshape: </label>
            <select name="trayshape">
                    <option value=""></option>

            <option value="Rectangular">Rectangular</option>

                <option value="Oval">Oval</option>

                <option value="Square">Square</option>

                    <option value="Insert">Insert</option>

                    <option value="Round">Round</option>

                    <option value="Open">Open</option>
            </select><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
    </form> 

    </body>
```

And the PHP:

```
   <body>

 <?php
    $con = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "");
           mysql_select_db ("delyn_db", $con);

    if (!$con)
        { 
         die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
        }

            $descrip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descrip']); 
            $height  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['height']);
            $width   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['width']);
            $depth   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['depth']);

            $varRange = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['trayrange']);
            $varType  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['traytype']);
            $varShape = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['trayshape']);
            $varImage = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['imagename']);

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM delyn WHERE 
                        description LIKE '%".$descrip."%' 
                    AND trayheight LIKE '%".$height."%' 
                    AND traywidth LIKE '%".$width."%' 
                    AND traydepth LIKE '%".$depth."%' 
                    AND trayrange LIKE '%".$varRange."%' 
                    AND traytype LIKE '%".$varType."%' 
                    AND trayshape LIKE '%".$varShape."%' ";


            $r_query = mysql_query($sql);

                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query))
                { 
                echo '<br /> Tool Code:   '. $row['toolcode'];
                echo '<br /> Description: '. $row['description']; 
                echo '<br /> Tray range:  '. $row['trayrange']; 
                echo '<br /> Tray type:   '. $row['traytype'];
                echo '<br /> Tray size:   '. $row['traysize']; 
                echo '<br /> Tray shape:  '. $row['trayshape'];  
                    echo '<br /> <img src="   '. $row['imagename'] . '"
                                    width="200" length="100">' . '<br />' . '<br />';  
                    }

                if (mysql_num_rows($r_query) <= 0){
                    echo 'No results match your search, please try
                                                  again';
                                  }
        ?>
                </body>
```

If anyone could help that would be great, thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

```
   <body>
        $scope = 20;
                $width_min = $width - $scope;
                $width_max = $width + $scope;
                $depth_min = $depth - $scope;
                $depth_max = $depth + $scope;
                $height_min = $height - $scope;
                $height_max = $height + $scope;

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM delyn WHERE 
                        description LIKE '%".$descrip."%' 
                    AND traywidth LIKE '%".$width."%'   
                    AND traydepth LIKE '%".$depth."%' 
                    AND trayheight LIKE '%".$height."%'
                    AND trayrange LIKE '%".$varRange."%' 
                    AND traytype LIKE '%".$varType."%' 
                    AND trayshape LIKE '%".$varShape."%'";

                if ($row = 0) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM delyn WHERE 
                        description LIKE '%".$descrip."%' 
                    AND (traywidth BETWEEN ".$width_min." AND ".$width_max.")  
                    AND (traydepth BETWEEN ".$depth_min." AND ".$depth_max.")  
                    AND (trayheight BETWEEN ".$height_min." AND ".$height_max.")  
                    AND trayrange LIKE '%".$varRange."%' 
                    AND traytype LIKE '%".$varType."%' 
                    AND trayshape LIKE '%".$varShape."%'";
                }
    <body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going with a fixed "upper" and "lower" margin, you can sort a list of your entries based upon an absolute calculation between the traywidth in your table and the inputted width by the user. Something like this:

```
select d.*, abs(d.traywidth - USER_SEARCH_INPUTTED_WIDTH) as WIDTH_ABS from delyn d order by WIDTH_ABS limit 20;
```

This will give you a list of nearby traywidths based upon the "USER_SEARCH_INPUTTED_WIDTH", for instance 252 as relative "distances" from what the user is after and what entries the database actually has.

Note: all columns you're allowing search in/for needs to be signed otherwise you'll end up with funky results (due to abs).

Comment: Could you possibly edit my code to show me where or how you'd implement this? I am trying myself but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Ditch those "traywidth LIKE '%".$width."%'" queries and approach the problem as I stated above. It should be very straight forward. To understand what is going on, go with only one characteristic first (i.e: traywidth) and move from there. Imo, one learns most from doing it oneself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SQL BETWEEN operator.

Comment: Good idea, are you able to use BETWEEN to find results that are with 10 off the exact result? Or within 10% of maybe?

Comment: Yup, should be possible. Do somthing like

AND traywidth BETWEEN $lowerWidth AND $upperWidth

Comment: How would you use this to compare it to what the user enters? Soif they enter "251" the code looks for the nearest results within say 20 of that?

Comment: You could simply define your $lowerWidth and $upperWidth to something like this:
$lowerWidth = $actualInputWidth - 20
$upperWidth = $actualInputWidth + 20

Comment: I have written something similar, but I still can't get the query to search for nearest results. The new code is above, anything I am missing? I've been staring at it for hours. Thanks for the help @Oppermann

Comment: What results do you get?
You probably have a problem with your datatypes. Maybe CONVERT can help you.